Why do PrestaShop e-mails arrive with wrongly encoded accented characters in the body?
I activated the SMTP email option in PrestaShop 8.2.0 and tried to send a test email through the dedicated section in the same page. I entered my email and I received the email.
I noticed that accented characters such as é are displayed as &egrave; in the body.
I want to understand if it is a bug or if there is some specific setting. The store is in Italian which requires accented characters.
I set all the settings to Italian and regenerated the emails but I still encounter the same problem. I don't know if this problem only refers to the pre-compiled text for the test email.
